# What is the best time to run runway friction tests?

Tags: safety, airport, runways

When is the best time to run runway friction tests?

And what is the optimum temperature to run them?

Comment: "optimal" w.r.t. which parameters/constraints?

Answer (score 2):

The friction will change over time due to temperature and moisture and other factors.

So, the best time to measure is shortly before a plane is about to land. In order to allow planning of alternatives, allow a longer time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of FAA sources on this, I don't know if other countries have similar guidance or not. The FAA information covers two reasons to measure runway friction: for maintenance, and for operations in winter (ice etc.).

For maintenance, the information is in [AC 150/5320-12C - *Measurement, Construction, and Maintenance of Skid Resistant Airport Pavement Surfaces*](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentNumber/150_5320-12). The PDFs seem to be corrupt for me (missing and blank pages), but [the draft version](https://www.faa.gov/documentlibrary/media/advisory_circular/draft-150-5320-12d.pdf) looks better. It recommends basing inspections on the minimum number of turbojet aircraft landings per runway end each day; see table 3-1 on page 8. The frequency ranges from a minimum of once per year for less than 15 landings up to once per week for more than 210 landings.

Because that's a draft and the published version doesn't work correctly for me it's possible that the published values are different.

For winter operations, the guidance is in [AC 150/5200-30D - *Airport Field Condition Assessments and Winter Operations Safety*](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.current/documentnumber/150_5200-30). There's no strictly defined frequency that I could see although it does mention four situations in which the airport should do a friction survey (section 5-2-1):

- There's a specific amount of ice or snow on the runway, and the operator "believes the information will be helpful"
- The runway centerline is contaminated for a distance of more than 500ft
- "Following all snow clearing, anti-icing, deicing, or sanding operations"
- Immediately after any incident or accident on the runway

Both ACs have a lot more information in them.